# How to add multiple data into multiple field in a table

Tags: php, mysql

my table fields are as below:

```
name | email | status | img_1 | img_2 | img_3 | img_4 | img_5 | img_6 | avail
```

so i want to add 6 images via a loop using php. but i cannot write the query to add images which are not static(i mean to say if some one add only 2 images or may be 1 images at the entry). pls help me. this is my basic query which i thought work.

```
$sql = "update product set img_".$dbfield." ='".$filename1."' where 
         id='".$iiid."'";
where $dbfield is the increment one by one to match the field name in img_1 img_2.
```

thank yoou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure what are achieving but I m assuming you want some think this.

```
$query = "UPDATE product SET";
$comma = " ";
$whitelist = array(
    'img_1',
    'img_2',
    'img_3',
    'img_4',
    'img_5',
     'img_6',
    // ...etc
);
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if( ! empty($val) && in_array($key, $whitelist)) {
        $query .= $comma . $key . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($val)) . "'";
        $comma = ", ";
    }
}
$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: thanx it really helps.

Comment: @DipayanDas if you found this ans is really helpfull. Don't forget to up vote or accept the ans it will help out others.

Comment: sorry i forgoty that.